# Let $f: X\to Y$ be continuous map , $g: Y\to Z$ be surjection, and $ f\circ g$ is continuous map. Then, $g$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, continuity

Let $f: X \to Y$ be continuous map , $g: Y \to Z$  be surjection, and $f \circ g$ is continuous map. Then, I would like to prove $g$ is continuous.

**My attempt** : Take arbitrary open set $U$ from $Z$, and pull back of $U$ by $f \circ g$ is open, and $f$ is continuous so.. (from here I cannot use $f$ is open mapping and I don't know where to use $g$ is surjective)

Another way is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: if the domain a function has the discrete topology, the any function is continuous; if the codomain has the indiscrete topology, then any function is continuous. But it's really hard for a function whose codomain has the discrete topology to be continuous.

Comment: Find a continuous bijection $f$ with discontinuous inverse $g$.

Comment: You consider $g \circ f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $X = \{0\}, Y = \mathbb R, Z = \{0, 1\}$,  where  $Z$ is given the discrete topology. Let $f : X \to Y, f(0) = 0$, and $g : Y \to Z,g(0) = 0$ and $g(y) = 1$ else. Then $g$ is surjective but not continuous and $f$ and $g \circ f$ are continuous.